# Result of SQL request SELECT

Tags: php, sql, json

when I selects values in my database, I get a dictionary of this form:

```
// -- My code    
$requete = $bdd -> prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ? AND id = ?');
    $requete -> execute(array($_GET['name'], $_GET['id']));
    $resultat = $requete ->fetch();
// --

  "User": {
        "id": "1",
        "0": "1",
        "name": "Hugo",
        "1": "Hugo",
        "password": "mdp",
        "2": "mdp",
        "matiere": "Math,Electro",
        "3": "Math,Electro",
        "roles": "User,SuperUser,bg,bg",
        "4": "User,SuperUser,bg"
    }
```

But i want :

```
"User": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Hugo",
        "password": "mdp",
        "matiere": "Math,Electro",
        "roles": "User,SuperUser,bg,bg"
    }
```

Do you have a solution for this problem?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$requte->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Read more about fetch styles here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php.